# How to pre-populate an app with a read-only store located in the app's bundle?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm trying to preload an app with read-only data contained in a `default.store` file located in the app's bundle.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct AppDemo: App {
    enum Schema: VersionedSchema {
        static var versionIdentifier: SwiftData.Schema.Version = .init(1, 0, 0)
        static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [Item.self]
    }
    
    let container: ModelContainer

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(container)
    }
    
    init() {
        do {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "store")!
            let schema = SwiftData.Schema(versionedSchema: Schema.self)
            let configuration = ModelConfiguration(url: url)
            container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: configuration)
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I've used the approach shown in [this example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-pre-populate-an-app-with-an-existing-swiftdata-database).

For reasons I don't know, it works perfectly in the simulator (iOS 17.0). But the same code fails when run on a device (iOS 17.0, still).

> Unresolved error loading container Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "An error occurred during persistent store migration." UserInfo={sourceURL=file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[UUID]/AppDemo.app/default.store, reason=Cannot migrate store in-place: error during SQL execution : attempt to write a readonly database, destinationURL=file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[UUID]/AppDemo.app/default.store, NSUnderlyingError=0x281c7ae20 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134110 "An error occurred during persistent store migration." UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=8, NSFilePath=/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/[UUID]/AppDemo.app/default.store, NSUnderlyingException=error during SQL execution : attempt to write a readonly database, reason=error during SQL execution : attempt to write a readonly database}}}

> CoreData: Attempt to add read-only file at path file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../AppDemo.app/default.store read/write. Adding it read-only instead. This will be a hard error in the future; you must specify the NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption.

How to configure the `ModelContainer` as read-only?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: perhaps try passing `allowsSave: false` in `ModelConfiguration.init`.

Comment: @Sweeper I tried it just now, but unfortunately the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the CoreData is attempting to add a read-only file as read/write. This results in a failure because the file is within your application's bundle, which is read-only. The application's bundle cannot be modified once the app has been installed, so any attempt to write to this location will fail.

You need to copy the `default.store` file from the bundle to the application's Documents directory (which is read/write) during the first launch of the app. Then, you can use this copied file for your ModelContainer.

```swift
init() {
    do {
        guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "store") else {
            fatalError("Failed to find default.store in app bundle")
        }

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let documentURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("default.store")

        // Only copy the store from the bundle to the Documents directory if it doesn't exist
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentURL.path) {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: documentURL)
        }

        let schema = SwiftData.Schema(versionedSchema: Schema.self)
        let configuration = ModelConfiguration(url: documentURL)
        container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: configuration)
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

W first get the URL of the `default.store` file in the app bundle. Then, we get the URL of the Documents directory and append "default.store" to it to get the destination URL. If the `default.store` file doesn't already exist in the Documents directory, we copy it from the bundle to the Documents directory. Finally, we use the `default.store` file in the Documents directory to create the `ModelContainer`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solution works. However, it has one drawback: as the store is copied, it doubles the size of the app. If no other solution is proposed, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Core Data supports read-only stores, and you can configure this using the `NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption` option. However, this is not directly available in the SwiftData framework you're using, as it abstracts the underlying Core Data functionality.